# Change a stateful class into stateless

Tags: scala

Here's a stateful class, but it's said that classes should be stateless in scala, and stateful object may get something wrong in multithreading environment. So can someone please help to transform this into a stateless class?

```
trait SwitchStrategy {
  def shouldSwitch: Boolean
}

object Strategies {

  def countdown(counts: Int): SwitchStrategy = {
    return new SwitchStrategy {
      private[this] var count = 0

      override def shouldSwitch: Boolean = {
        count += 1
        return if (count >= counts) {
          count = 0;
          true
        } else false
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Stateless object has no state, you want an immutable object that has state but it can't be changed.

Comment: Did we manage to answer your question?

Comment: @slouc yes, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your whole problem is based on maintaining state and there's no "magical syntax" to eliminate it. Method `shouldSwitch` is not referentially transparent:

```
val s = Strategies.countdown(3)
println(s.shouldSwitch) // false
println(s.shouldSwitch) // false
println(s.shouldSwitch) // true
```

If you want to use the functional paradigm, taking an imperative solution that uses mutable state and rewriting it isn't really a good approach. I don't know the external details of your program so I can't really help to transform it. First thing you obviously need to do is to remove the mutable state your `SwitchStrategy` depends on. One common solution is to put the burden of supplying the state info on the caller, which would in this case mean that the calles of `shouldSwitch` provides the count.

Answer (score 1):

Fully functional approach to handling state is called state monad.

More information here: http://eed3si9n.com/learning-scalaz/State.html or here: http://timperrett.com/2013/11/25/understanding-state-monad/

There is no syntax or simple refactoring that would allow you to change from one style to the other.

In simple terms:

To achieve your expected result, instead of modifying internal state, each operation should return a pair of `(Result, NewState)` and in consecutive operations you should throw away previous state and use the new returned one.

Answer (score 1):

(mutable) State isn't always bad, and sometimes is unavoidable. Iterators have state, and so do I/O streams ... Try writing something useful without them.
It will also not necessarily "get something wrong in a multithreading environment" ... especially, if you don't share your state holders between threads.

Having said that, stateless (or rather referentially-transparent) code is easier to reason about, and for that reason tends to be more reliable and robust. So, when you can get around the "naive" requirement to have state, it is usually a good idea to do it.

In this case, I think, something like this might work:

```
   trait SwitchStrategy { 
      def shouldSwitch: Boolean
      def next: SwitchStrategy        


      @tailrec
      final def apply[T](strategy: T => T)(initial: T): T = 
        if(shouldSwitch) initial else next(strategy)(strategy(initial))
   }   

   case class CountDown(n: Int) extends SwitchStrategy {
      def next = n match {
         case 0 => this
         case _ => copy(n-1)
      }
      def shouldSwitch = n == 0
   }
```

You can then use it like this for example:

```
   def makeZero = CountDown(10) { n:Int => n - 1 } (10)
   def plus(a: Int, b: Int) = CountDown(a) { n: Int => n + 1} (b)
   def pow(a: Int, b: Int) = CountDown(b-1) { n: Long => n * a } (a)
```

etc.